# Is this set of tuples countable?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We toss a fair coin until we get two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails. Each sequence of $n$ coin tosses has a probability of $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

I was wondering if the sample space

$\Omega:=\{\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots\omega_n)\mid \omega_i\in\{\text{head, tail}\}\text{ and } \omega_{n-1}=\omega_n,~\text{ where }n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

is countable?

Maybe something like $\varphi:\Omega\to\mathbb{N}$, where
\begin{align*}
\varphi(\omega)=\begin{cases}n,& \text{ if } \omega_n=\text{head}\\n-1,&\text{ if } \omega_n=\text{tail}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
works but I am not sure. Or is $\Omega$ uncountable?

Comment: Your function doesn't distinguish between the sequences $011$ and $0100$, for instance

Comment: If you consider the set of finite length binary strings, these guys are in bijection with the naturals and your sequences can be naturally identified with a subset of them (e.g., with tails as $0$ and heads as $1$)

Comment: It is a standard theorem that a countable union of finite or countable sets is finite or countable. Your set is the countable union over $n$ of the set of valid sequences of length $n$.